# Update DataGrid Checkbox State By Property that Depends on Other Property

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, binding

I have a model, which contains CanDrawProperty. I want to bind this property to IsEnabled property of DataGrid CheckBox:

```
public class Series : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<DropPhoto> _dropPhotosSeries;
    public ObservableCollection<DropPhoto> DropPhotosSeries
    {
        get
        {
            return _dropPhotosSeries;
        }
        set
        {
            _dropPhotosSeries = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DropPhotosSeries"));
        }
    }

    private bool _canDrawPlot;
    public bool CanDrawPlot
    {
        get
        {
            if (_dropPhotosSeries?.Where(x => x.Drop.RadiusInMeters != null).ToList().Count > 1)
            {
                _canDrawPlot = true;
                return _canDrawPlot;
            }

            _canDrawPlot = false;
            return _canDrawPlot;
        }
        set
        {
            _canDrawPlot = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CanDrawPlot"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

I want to update my Datagrid CheckBox IsEnabled state based on CanDrawPlot property of this model. But this doesn't seem to work. XAML for DataGrid:

```
                    <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" ClipToBounds="True" ItemsSource="{Binding User.UserSeries}" SelectionChanged="SeriesDataGrid_OnSelectionChanged" Name="SeriesDataGrid">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserResize="False">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox IsEnabled="{Binding CanDrawPlot}" Checked="ChooseSeries_Checked" x:Name="ChooseSeries" Height="25"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

I have class User. It contains UserSeries. UserSeries has property CanDrawPlot:

```
public class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Series> _userSeries;
    public ObservableCollection<Series> UserSeries
    {
        get
        {
            return _userSeries;
        }
        set
        {
            _userSeries = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("UserSeries"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the `User.UserSeries` a collection of `Series` class? Also, why do you set `_canDrawPlot` in property getter?

Comment: yes it is. It doesn't metter this property doesn't meant to be setted anyway. I could just return true or false in getter depending on condition

Comment: private bool _canDrawPlot;
        public bool CanDrawPlot
        {
            get
            {
                if (_dropPhotosSeries?.Where(x => x.Drop.RadiusInMeters != null).ToList().Count > 1)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                _canDrawPlot = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CanDrawPlot"));
            }
        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following lines to your code

In the xaml:
You need to add to bindinig the UpdateSourceTrigger

```
<CheckBox IsEnabled="{Binding CanDrawPlot,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Checked="ChooseSeries_Checked" x:Name="ChooseSeries" Height="25"/>
```

And in the xaml.cs you need to creat an instance of Series class

For example:

```
private Series series = new Series ();
```

And in the constructor of the xaml.cs you need to write:

```
DataContext = series;
```

Successfully.

Comment: Still nothig. CheckBox doesn't seems to notice, that CanDrawPlot property have changed